# How to skip external redirection page using history back function?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, redirect, navigation

Let's say an external site has a redirection page before actually moving to the internal site when user clicks the link.
This internal site only has a button that will let you go back using
[History.back()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back) or .go(-x). I can only do changes on the internal site.

What's happening here is that we now have a "loop" that redirects to the external redirection page using history.back(), and then the user will be redirected once again to the internal site.

Flow:

External site -> user clicks on internal site link -> external site sends user to external redirection page -> user redirects to visit the internal site -> user click history.back button -> user get redirected to external redirection page -> user redirects to visit the internal site again

**I basically do not want the user to end up at the internal site after users clicks the history.back button.**

I thought about saving page visit in localstorage, so that if it gets redirected back to the internal site again it will instead do history.go(-2).
I am also aware of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer document.referrer, but that will also degrade the UX since the user gets redirected back and forth at least once.

The only solution I could think of is having a query parameter upon visiting the internal site someurl.com/?redirects=2, so that we could do history.go(-redirects). However, that requires the external site to decide how many redirects it has.

Is it possible to know if user comes from a redirection page from the external site? Is there a way so that we can skip the external redirection page and just go straight to the external page?

Comment: What site do you have control over? Just the "internal" site?

Comment: Yes, the internal site is the one I have control over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.location.replace is there for exactly the same requirement, please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Assuming that the external rediection page contains only the logic for rediection and no content, they should have used location.replace for redirection to have a clean state of history.

I know that you do not have control over external site but I just wanted to help in case you can ask someone to make changes there :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to the problem, but my approach does use ***document.referrer***.

Regarding UX degradation when using document.referrer, it should be barely noticeable as long as your clientside code is optimized.

Also, you might be interested to read [this MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/How_long_is_too_long).
My solution approach is attached here:

```js
const isExternalURL = (url) => new URL(url).origin !== location.origin;

function checkExternalURL() {
  const referrerPage = document.referrer;
  if (referrerPage == undefined) return false;
  return isExternalURL(referrerPage);
}

if (checkExternalURL()) {
  console.log("External URL Detected");
} else {
  console.log("Internal URL Detected");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How will this solve the flow problem if user clicks "history.back()" button on the internal site and user gets to the external redirection page which gets redirected to the internal site again? Is there a way so that we can skip the external redirection page and just go straight to the external page?

Comment: It will handle this flow too, since document.referrer property returns the URL of the document that loaded the current document. And regarding skipping external redirection page, I am not clear about your requirements.

Comment: It's true that the code you've provided checks if user comes from an external url, but is it possible to know if that url is an redirection page from the external site? I don't want the user to end back up on the internal site

Comment: Unfortunately, using current logic, No. If it is an external site then you can not know it using clientside code. You have to go serverside to know this.